# Where are the Forwarding Implementations mentioned in the ByteBuddy tutorial?

Tags: byte-buddy

The [ByteBuddy tutorial](https://bytebuddy.net/#/tutorial) says, in part:

> The `Forwarding` implementations allows to simply forward a method call to another instance of the same type as the declaring type of an intercepted method. The same result can be achieved using a `MethodDelegation`. However, by `Forwarding` a simpler delegation model is applied which can cover use cases where no target method discovery is required.

I don't see `Forwarding` in [the Javadoc index](https://javadoc.io/static/net.bytebuddy/byte-buddy/1.10.8/index-all.html#I:F).  Where did it go, or what is it now?

Answer (score 0):

Good catch, the documentation is outdated, unfortunately. The Forwarding instrumentation was resolved into the MethodCall instrumentation which can achieve the same thing whilst being more flexible.